# Watch text file over http for changes

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I plan to deploy a Google App engine app which will periodically read a public "text" file over the internet and perform some action every time the file has some updates.
Is there an efficient way to achieve this rather than opening and closing a stream all the time?
Apart from polling every few mins, is there any alternative?

(I would have no control over the "text" file placed on the internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you cannot get the server where the file is located to tell you when it has changed you need to poll.  You may be able to use long polling where the connection is kept open between requests to avoid the TCP/IP connection overhead, but that makes the solution more complex.

Note that if the data is meant to be consumed there will be an API.  If not, consider asking for one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, there is no API and moreover, this solution will be applied to other Servers (which I do not own) too.

Comment: Well, such is the life of web page scrapers.